# Android - Intentionally make Grid-view items overlap vertically

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view, android-gridview

I am populating a RecyclerView with [this seekbar slider library](https://github.com/Ramotion/fluid-slider-android).
Since this seekbar slider have a progress bubble  which only appears upon interacting with seekbar there's an added height to the seekbar itself (Blue bar + extra white space on top of it) which is a part of slider. which looks like the image below on a 2 column gridview.

[image]

My goal is to make items of grid-view overlap vertically by some `dp` so that I can rid of the extra white space in between bars. Which will look like this.

[image]

I have seen people doing it with LinerLayoutManager with a custom class but I am using recyclerView with GridLayoutManager and I am not sure how to archive it.

Comment: Have you tried using an item decorator to your recyclerview?

Comment: Yes, I tried it just now and it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by using a custom item decorator class.

```
public class ItemDecoratorGridView  extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

private final static int vertOverlap = -180;

@Override
public void getItemOffsets (Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    outRect.set(0, vertOverlap, 0, 0);

}
}
```

and apply to your adapter class like this

`adapter.addItemDecoration(new ItemDecoratorGridView());`